# iOS - Swift How to draw a UIView with double border like storyboards?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikit, ios11

I know how to create a simple single line border around a UIView. However, I see that the XCode storyboard has a double lined white to gray border, and want to replicate this look.

**Is there a way to add a double lined border with different colors to UIView using built in UIKit properties?**

```
view.layer.borderWidth = 1
view.layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
view.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

[image]

Comment: just draw another view with the inset of the size of the line weight

Comment: simply add a sublayer with borderwidth and bordercolor and add it to your uiview. the frame or rect given to the sublayer at the time initialising should be less than the frame or rect of the uiview such that difference between sublayer rect width and height and uiview = borderwidth.

Comment: It's just seeing how many iOS and MacOS elements are written using their own frameworks, I was curious if there's something new which creates effect like this without the hassle of layers, nested subviews, etc.